# Mount "hosts" in Plack::Builder

Tags: perl, plack, psgi

The Synopsis for the [Plack::Builder](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Builder) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6046857/869025) says:

```
# in .psgi
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = sub { ... };

builder {
    mount "/foo" => builder {
        enable "Foo";
        $app;
    };

    mount "/bar" => $app2;
    mount "http://example.com/" => builder { $app3 };
};
```

I tried the following:

```
use Plack::Builder;
my $app1 = sub { return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [ "Hello 1"] ]; };
my $app2 = sub { return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [ "Hello 2"] ]; };
my $app3 = sub { return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [ "Hello 3"] ]; };

builder {
        mount "/a1" => builder { $app1 };
        mount "http://myhost.com" => builder{ $app2 };
        mount "/" => builder{ $app3 };
}
```

But when tried to run it with `plackup` got:

> Error while loading /tmp/app.psgi: Paths need to start with / at
>   /home/cw/.anyenv/envs/plenv/versions/5.20.3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.3/Plack/Builder.pm
>   line 108.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see this mentioned explicitly in the documentation, but you have to include a path component in addition to the hostname, e.g. `http://myhost.com/foo`. Change

```
mount "http://myhost.com" => builder{ $app2 };
```

to

```
mount "http://myhost.com/" => builder{ $app2 };
```

(i.e. `/` on host `myhost.com`)

The relevant code is in [Plack::App::URLMap](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0037/lib/Plack/App/URLMap.pm#L16) (`mount` simply calls Plack::App::URLMap's `map` method):

```
if ($location =~ m!^https?://(.*?)(/.*)!) {
    $host     = $1;
    $location = $2;
}
```

Comment: OMG. This is really a stupid bug. ;( Would be nice to have this explicitly documented. Thank you! The error message is confusing - it talks about the _start_. ;)

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug, per se, although the documentation could be clearer. You're supposed to provide both a hostname and a location. `http://myhost.com/` corresponds to `/` on `myhost.com`; `http://myhost.com` doesn't specify a location, just a hostname.

Comment: mean bug in _my_ code :) - is has logic to have a `/` at the end. Just the doc should be cleaner. Thanx. :)

Comment: Well don't hesitate to open a pull request or issue to make the error less confusing :) https://github.com/plack/Plack